# Server-Friendly Minecraft Elevator?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there a server-friendly redstone elevator I can build in Minecraft? The "zipper" version doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the speed by increasing the delay on each of the repeaters?  I've heard people have had success with that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this one should work.